# Specify "Accept:" header parameter in a GWT JSONP request

Tags: java, gwt, jsonp

Is it possible to specify the `Accept:` header parameter in a GWT JSONP request? I'm using the `JsonpRequestBuilder` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON-P is about adding a `<script>` element to the page (the server will then return JavaScript that will callback a JS function of yours with some data); there's no way to tweak the request made by the browser in this case.

Comment: Indeed, but it's strange that some browsers (namely, Chromium) do not send any `Accept:` header param when doing this request. Especially that the `JsonpRequest` class `send()` function *do* specify the script type ("text/javascript").

Comment: Well, more precisely browsers **do** send an `Accept: */*` for a script request, whatever the `<script>` type... I tested with Chromium  and Firefox on Linux.